# java error: double cannot be dereferenced

Tags: java, arrays, random, numbers

ok so i need to generate 7 random numbers between 1 and 100 and have the max be printed on the screen. however, when i compile this code:

```
public class ArrayofTemperatures
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {

      double [] temp = new double [7];
      int index;
      double max;
      double random = Math.random() * 100 + 1;

      temp[0] = random.nextDouble();
      max = temp[0];
      for (index = 1; index < temp.length; index++)
      {
         temp[index] = random.nextDouble();
         if (temp[index] > max)
            max = temp[index];

      }

      System.out.println("The highest score is: " + max);
   }
}
```

I get these two errors:

> ArrayofTemperatures.java:12: error: double cannot be dereferenced
>   temp[0] = random.nextDouble();
>
> ArrayofTemperatures.java:16: error: double cannot be dereferenced
>             temp[index] = random.nextDouble();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got confused.

This statement produces a single `double` value :

```
double random = Math.random() * 100 + 1;
```

If you want a Random generator, use

```
Random random = new Random ();
```

Then `random.nextDouble()` would produce a number between 0.0 and 1.0.

The alternative is to replace the calls to `random.nextDouble()` with `Math.random()`.

Comment: ok thank you! i got rid of the error, however the number will only generate between 0.0 and 1.0 like you said. how can i get the number to generate between 1 and 100 if you dont mind answering another question

Comment: @ValRadcliffe You can write a method that returns `Math.random() * 100 + 1` or `random.nextDouble() * 100 + 1` (depending on whether you wish to use the static `Math.random()` method or an instance method of `Random` class).

Comment: thank you again!! im taking a beginner level java class and its pretty hard sometimes!

Answer (score 0):

`random` is the primitive type `double`, and has therefore no methods, also no `nextDouble`.

I assume you wanted to use `Random` class.